# White screen appearing in java when i use g.drawString

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, awt

So I'm supposed to make a game that has a score in its HUD but whenever i use the code

```
g.drawString("Score: " + score, 15, 64);
//score is a variable
```

it appears a white screen like this

[image]

the full code of the HUD is like this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HUD {

public static int HEALTH = 800;

private static int gvalue = 255;

public int score = 0;
public int level = 1;

   public void tick(){
         HEALTH = MainGame.clamp(HEALTH, 0, 800);

         gvalue = MainGame.clamp(gvalue, 0, 255);
         gvalue = HEALTH/4;

         score++;
   }

public void render(Graphics g){
       g.setColor(Color.gray);
       g.fillRect(15, 15, 200, 30);
       g.setColor(new Color(70, gvalue, 0));
       g.fillRect(15, 15, (HEALTH / 4) , 30);
       g.setColor(Color.white);
       g.drawRect(15, 15, 100 * 2, 30);

       g.drawString("Score: " + score, 15, 64);
       //the line above though, when i remove it, it completely works
   }

  public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    }
```

P.S I have objects, windows, colors, etc. but they are in other classes. 
P.P.S When I remove, the said line, it works fine.

Comment: You need to add background color using .setBackground(Color.black);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything declaring font or font color...

```
g.setColor(Color.black);
Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, (int) Math.round(20 * scaleX));
g.setFont(font);
g.drawString("Score: " + score, 15, 64);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There are two types of people in this world, type 1: `Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13)` type 2: `g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13))`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is almost 4 years old, but I'm following the same tutorial on youtube and got the same problem. I also found a solution, so posting here in case other people stumble across this thread:

Here is what solved it in my case:
In the Game class (where you have the game loop and render / tick method), look in the render method.
In my case, I had to change the number in createBufferStrategy() from 2 to 3.
So this code now works:

```
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
```

And I can now successfully g.drawString in the HUD class

Comment: Can you expand on this code example?